# Design a mobile app for multiscreen resolutions

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I'm really new with flex. I want to develop an app for multiscreen resolutions. I can't figure out exactly what i  need to do.

I read this article [here](http://renaun.com/blog/2011/10/customizing-flex-applicationdpi-for-a-multiple-screen-size-application/) but it still it's not that clear what i have to do.

Can anyone explain how can i keep the same size and design across multiple resolutions?

How can i achieve Density independence ?

Do i need to have 3 different resolutions for a background picture for example?

What screen resolutions does my background image needs to be ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To achieve density independence and hit multiple screen resolutions, you need to be prepared for any and every screen possible. From the low-res iPhone 3/GS to the super hi-res Nexus 10. There is no specific screen resolution your background image needs to be because, well, there are hundreds of resolutions it will need to be.

Instead of making the background a set resolution, consider constructing it with code. Either through a repeatable tile or by using multiple images and putting them together to form your background.

You definitely will want to use one image for each Adobe resolution (160dpi, 240dpi, and 320dpi). You can do that by using this:

```
<s:Image>
    <s:source>
        <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource
            source160dpi="@Embed('assets/ui/images/phone/info-image-160.png')" 
            source240dpi="@Embed('assets/ui/images/phone/info-image-240.png')" 
            source320dpi="@Embed('assets/ui/images/phone/info-image-320.png')" />
    </s:source>
</s:Image>
```

Assuming you created everything in vector, this is relatively simple. Just take the image you designed for 160 (which is what most people seem to design for) and enlarge it to 150% for 240dpi and 200% for 320dpi.

For true density independence, you also need to make sure you are not using `applicationDPI` in your application tags as that will force a specific resolution.

For CSS, you should follow this format (taken directly from the first link below)

```
    @media (application-dpi: 160) {

        s|Button {
            fontSize: 10;
        }
    }

    /* IOS only @ 240dpi */
    @media (application-dpi: 240) and (os-platform: "IOS") {
        s|Button {
            fontSize: 11;
        }
    }

    /* IOS at 160dpi or Android @ 160dpi */
    @media (os-platform: "IOS") and (application-dpi:160), (os-platform: "ANDROID") and (application-dpi: 160) {
        s|Button {
            fontSize: 13;        
        }
    }
```

You need to consider everything. Images, fonts/font sizes, component sizing, hardcoded component placemenets, etc. You can take a look at the `Capabilities` class for any idea of what kind of data is available to you at run time as well. If you end up getting incorrect values using things like stage.stageHeight, consider using `FlexGlobals.topApplication.sys(tem?)Manager.screen.height` instead. That accounts for DPI whereas stageHeight does not.

Also Read:

- [Support multiple screen sizes and DPI values in a mobile
  application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html)